# How to customize Yii2 Gridview Search Model Fields

Tags: gridview, yii2

I've used Gii to generate CRUD models, views, and a controller.

The table/model I'm using is for a raffle result, which contains an `id`, a `reset_at` (datetime), and a `winner_id` which is a foreign key to a user table. The model also has a method to get all users that were entered into the raffle via a junction table.

I am using Kartik's gridview, and I would like the `reset_at` field to be a date picker, and the winner_id to instead be the winner's username. I have easily set up the table rows to show the formatted date and the winner's username. The problem is that the search fields at the top are still a `datetime` (string) and a `winner_id` (integer).

I have attempted to adjust the search model by changing the rules method from something like:

```
return [
    [['id', 'winner_id'], 'integer'],
    [['reset_at'], 'safe'],
];
```

to

```
return [
    [['reset_at', 'winner_id'], 'safe'],
];
```

I am not using the `id` column in the gridview. I then attempt to read the `winner_id` as a string, do a find to get the user by username equaling the string, and use it's id in the filtering like so:

```
// grid filtering conditions
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'id' => $this->id,
    'reset_at' => $this->reset_at,
    'winner_id' => $winner->id,
]);
```

I've also tried something similar with the date string, where I adjust the filter to be a datetime that is between, etc. However when I do this, the search fields disappear from the top of the columns.

How do I customize these results, or even add entirely custom attributes to the gridview for custom filtering?

**Update:**
As requested here is my search model (with code changes following [this guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview))

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\Raffle;

/**
 * RaffleSearch represents the model behind the search form of `common\models\Raffle`.
 */
class RaffleSearch extends Raffle
{
    public $winner;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'winner_id'], 'integer'],
            [['reset_at', 'winner'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Raffle::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
        
        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['winner'] = [
            'asc' => ['app_user.username' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['app_user.username' => SORT_DESC],
        ];

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'reset_at' => $this->reset_at,
            'winner_id' => $this->winner_id,
        ])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'app_user.username', $this->winner]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will help you get the desired result: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I've seen that, it doesn't seem to help me as I end up with bad queries that are selecting from a table that's not in the query.

Comment: Can you post your entire search method?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco posted the whole model

Comment: Include this next to initial query `$query = Raffle::find();` next line this `$query->joinWith(['USER_TABLE_RELATION_NAME']);`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Thanks! that solved one half of my issue, hoping it will help me figure out the second

Comment: You bet, that link what i shared in my first comment, explain everything step by step.

Comment: It doesn't quite help with the date part unfortunately

Comment: Search by date? Just use a range or between, or which is better, make a raw sql query and then express it in to the active query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218325/discussion-between-sharf-and-serghei-leonenco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add a join table to your query:

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Raffle::find();

        $query->joinWith(['USER_TABLE_RELATION_NAME']); //Change to you relation name
        ...
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'USER_TABLE.name', $this->winner]);
        ...
```

> It doesn't quite help with the date part unfortunately, I plan on using a between, but I'm very rusty with yii's querying. I'm not sure how to use that in active query

To search between the dates you can use this:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['BETWEEN', 'YOUR_DATE_TABLE_FIELD', $this->start_date, $this->end_date]);
```

And as an example for other options, check this answers as well: [Search between two dates in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325734/search-between-two-dates-in-yii2)